# Extract data from column and use it to update another column

Tags: mysql, database, extract

I have XML data in my database column. I want to extract data and paste it in a new column

what I have

```
id         data                          col1         col2
----------------------------------------------------------
1         <col1>data1</col1>
          <col2>data2</col2>
```

What I need

```
id         data                          col1         col2
----------------------------------------------------------
1                                        data1        data2
```

Can I do it with SQL only?
something like

```
UPDATE database SET col1 = extract('data', 'data1')...
```

thank you.

Comment: I would run a php script to retrieve each row, extract all the text between <cols> and update

Comment: Check out the extractvalues() function in mysql. However, if your data is not proper xml, then you may have to revert to string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have mysql version 5.7 then you can do the following using mysql xml functions:

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = ExtractValue(data, '/col1'), col2 = ExtractValue(data, '/col2');
```

***Test data and output:***

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    data TEXT,
    col1 VARCHAR(255),
    col2 VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO t1 (id, data) VALUES
(1, '<col1>data1</col1><col2>data2</col2>');

SELECT * FROM t1;

UPDATE t1 SET col1 = ExtractValue(data, '/col1'), col2 = ExtractValue(data, '/col2');

SELECT * FROM t1;
```

**Before update:**

```
+----+--------------------------------------+------+------+
| id | data                                 | col1 | col2 |
+----+--------------------------------------+------+------+
|  1 | <col1>data1</col1><col2>data2</col2> | NULL | NULL |
+----+--------------------------------------+------+------+
```

**After update:**

```
+----+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+
| id | data                                 | col1  | col2  |
+----+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+
|  1 | <col1>data1</col1><col2>data2</col2> | data1 | data2 |
+----+--------------------------------------+-------+-------+
```